# iOS 8+ lower background audio when playing MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: audio, video, ios8, mpmovieplayercontroller, avaudiosession

I'm working on an app iOS8+ and I have a question regarding background audio when playing video/audio on MPMoviePlayerController.

What I'd like to do is :

- **Best solution** : Lower the background audio music while the video/audio is playing and putting it back to full volume when the video/audio stops.
- **Good solution** : Stop the background audio music while the video/audio is playing and putting it back when the video/audio stops. I managed to do that but only with iTunes music, not with other apps (Spotify, SoundClound). I can stop the background audio on Spotify when I'm playing the video, but there is no way make it play again at the end.

Here are the solutions I thought about :

- **Solutions 1** : Detect other apps playing audio in background and act on them. It seems not possible.
- **Solutions 2** : Play with the AVAudioSession categories. This is what I'm trying to do right now but couldn't have the behaviour I want. *AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient* allows me to have the video and audio background playing together but no way to lower background audio (the good thing is that I don't have to restart background audio).
  *AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient* (and others) stops the background audio but no way to make it restart at the end.

Do you guys have tips on how to achieve such a thing ?

Thank you very much for your time